# Tkinter and ConfigParser

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, configparser

I am writing a small program where there are two entry widgets that load the path from the configuration file.Is it possible to insert a value into each entry widget (values in the config are in order)?I only managed to insert values into one widget. And all the paths from the Input_311 config section are inserted there, but I only need one path in one widget.
I plan on making a lot more Entry Widgets, I would like to optimize the insertion process.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't post code in image.  Copy the code in text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have used tkinter variables in those `Entry` widgets, I would suggest to create a list to store those tkinter variables, then use for loop to insert values into those `Entry` widgets as below:

```py
variables = [self.entry1Var1, self.entry2Var2, ...]

for var, path in zip(variables, CONFIG['Input_311'].values()):
    var.set(path)
```

Comment: Could you explain what the expression zip (...) means?

Comment: @Max See official document on [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: I recieve an error " AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'set' "

Comment: I used the tkinter variables, not the `Entry` widgets.

Comment: variables = [self.entry_1, self.entry_2]
for var, path in zip(variables, CONFIG['Input_311'].values()): 
     var.set(path)

I write my entry's widgets, but error the same.

Comment: You have used `Entry` widgets in `variables`, so you need to call `var.insert(...)` instead.  As I said in my answer, I would suggest to use those tkinter variables (`StringVar`) instead.

Comment: OMG, it's working! 
Thank you very much for the help. I'm new in programming.

Answer (score 0):

With all advices, answer for my question is:

```
variables = [self.entry_1, self.entry_2]
for var, path in zip(variables, CONFIG['Input_311'].values()):
    var.insert(0, path)
```